# In Django can you have one template base layer inheriting from another?

Tags: html, django, templates, inheritance, django-templates

In Django can you have one template base layer inheriting from another?

For example:

base.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
     <html>

     {% load staticfiles %}

     <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <title>Cloud Fabric || Product Calculator</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/pure/0.5.0/pure-min.css">

{% block additionalStyles %}

    <link rel="stylesheet" type= "text/css" href = "{% static 'fabric/editionsStylesheet.css' %}" />

    {% endblock additionalStyles %}

    </head>

    <body>

    <div id="header">
        <h1 id="HeaderH1"><i>{{EditionName}}</i></h1>
    </div>

    {% block content %}

    {% endblock content %}

    </body>
    </html>
```

So that will be the main base layer now is there a way to make another base layer to inherit from it for different parts of a website? like so:

base2.html

```
 {% extends "base.html" %}

 {% block additionalStyles %}

    {% load staticfiles %}
<link rel="stylesheet" type= "text/css" href = "{% static 'fabric/monthlyEditionsStylesheet.css' %}" />

{% endblock additionalStyles %}

{% block content %}


    <h1 id="chooseMonthH1">Choose The Monthly Range:</h1>
                                                            {% block monthlyForm %}




    {% endblock monthlyForm %}

         <button type="submit" class="pure-button pure-button-primary" id="subButton">Submit</button>

    {% block formend %}

         </form>

    {% endblock formend %}

</div>

{% endblock content %}
```

So then further html can inherit from base2.html? i have already tried this but the form stopped working and the css messed up.

Answer (score 0):

Your `base2.html` template overwrites contents of the `additionalStyles` block from the `base.html` template.

To preserve parent's block content, you must use the magic `block.super` variable like this:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block additionalStyles %}
    {{ block.super }}
    <link ... >
{% endblock additionalStyles %}
```

The above notation appends content to the `additionalStyles` block.